# Can't run executable from command window

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run some C++ code from my windows command prompt. So I go

```
g++ NameOfFile -o par
./par.out
```

Then it tells me that `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Before it didn't recognize `g++` as a command and I fixed it in the system variables by adding `C:\MinGW\bin` but shouldn't this had also added `.`? How can I add it or otherwise run my executable? If I go to my files and just click the executable file it does run by the way.

Comment: The `./<file>` syntax is how you launch things in Linux.  In Windows, just use `par` or `par.out`; whatever the executable file is named.

Comment: You seem to be on Windows, not UNIX, so did you mean `.\par.exe`?

Comment: par.exe does run it! Thank you. I swear I was able to use `.` before though, but I'm just glad this works now, thanks.

Comment: You can use dot but it's unnecessary. There is an implied `.\ `  before filenames. Some parts of Windows if given a unix path will fix it to a Windows path. So sometimes in some places it will fix forward slashes and in others it will error.